# Update State's property from axios response, if difference between them

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, setstate

I want to find a way to compare the upcoming response from axios to the current state's property, and only if they are different, then use setState with the response to replace that property. Otherwise skip the usage of setState, because they are equal

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Readonly<Props>, nextState: Readonly<State>): boolean {

        if (nextProps.isReloading !== this.state.isReloading) {
            // HERE we just confirm to proceed and change this prop
            this.setState({
                isReloading: nextProps.isReloading,
            });
            getData('/some-end-point')
                    .then((response: any) => { 
                      const newItems = response.data;
```

> Already logged and confirmed they are equal, but the next line returns NO

```
                     this.state.items == newItems ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

> And after that only if different, update current state with the new one

```
                    })
                    .catch((error: any) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that `newItems` is an array,

just comparing them with `==` or `===` would not work (various reasons would not get into that)

is there any benefit in not replacing `this.state.items` if it's same?

If it's so important that you not call `setState` if they are same, you can compare them by looping the array and comparing each element of the array

```
newItems.length === this.state.items.length && newItems.sort().every((value, index)=> value === this.state.items.sort()[index]);
```

This is assuming that each element in your array is a `string` or `number`, if any of the elements is another array or is an object, you have to do a similar comparison in each element

You could use lodash `isEqual` to do this I assume

Comment: Comparing with === don't work as you've said, i forgot to mention that. Both arrays and filled with objects with alot of different keys, so i wanted to find a better solution, if possible, without comparison of each element everytime. Skipping setting state is needed, because alot of refreshing need to be done clientside for now. I will check lodash

Comment: Yea I totally get you. Try lodash or any library that has `deep-equal` (That's the kind of comparison you are searching for)